# How to create a universal app with xcode 4.3.3 for multiple views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

i have taken the option universal app while creating the application . I got an appdelegate and a viewcontroller with 2 xibs . one for iphone and 1 for ipad . If i want to use another view controller should i take 2 classes with 2 view controllers or single class with 2 xibs.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you should be able to just have another view controller and use the conditional statement from the template when you initialize it:

```
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
    {
           self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } 
    else 
    {
           self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
```

Where @"ViewController_iPhone/iPad" are your two separate nibs. I'd recommend having a different class for each view as well.

Comment: you mean to say that writing separate classes for both iphone and ipad.I want to use a single view controller class with 2 xib files so that it should auto detect the iphone and ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Both will work. You can use multiple Xib one for iphone and one for iPad with same class. But never forget to set file owners for each Xib.

Comment: you mean to say that writing separate classes for both iphone and ipad.I want to use a single view controller class with 2 xib files so that it should auto detect the iphone and ipad.

Comment: You are right dear you can create one class and link this class with two xib's.